# List of Map.Entry<String,String>

Tags: java, list

how to convert a list of `Map.Entry<String, String>` to a `String`?

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> : [AREA_DS_ID=1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33, PROJECTS_ID=13,78,267,18,28,33,55,99, SIGNAL_NAME=a, ASSESSMENTNAME=a]
// these are the values which I need to convert into String.
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @StefanWarminski is this ok now buddy?

Comment: What's the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: @AnujVictor You got like 5 guys asking you what you need.  Just type it in the question.  "WHAT I WANT": xyz...

Comment: i want a String of array containing key value pair of map in each indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's you mean ?? you want to convert map element( key=value) to string value ??? for this, you can use a loop on map entry set and read key and value of map elements and create custom string and concat all list:

```
String resultString ="" ;
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.EntrySet())
{
   String key = entry.getKey();
   String value = entry.getValue();  
   // create custom string for each map element
   String testString = key + "=" + value;
   resultString +=  testString ;
}
```

for a list of Map you can define loop on list :

```
for(Map<String,String> map : list)
{
  // use map such above code
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanx man it worked, but what if i want to add it in an String array as a key value pair?

Comment: Hint: string concatination is a loop is not a good (performant) idea. Use a `StringBuilder` instead

Comment: @AnujVictor You can add the created string to a list and convert the list after your loop `String[] entries = entryList.toArray(new String[entryList.size()]);`

Comment: @StefanWarminski actually its a List<Map.Entry<String,String>> so i guess cant be converted, its throughing  java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Comment: @M2E67 instead of concatenating to a String is it possible to add it in a String array?

Comment: @StefanWarminski in the above solution, the String is coming out like this----List: AREA_DS_ID=1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33SIGNAL_NAME=hestonPROJECTS_ID=13,78,267,18,28,33,55,99SIGNAL_NAME=aASSESSMENTNAME=aSOMETHING=INTERESTING.

how to store it as a key value pair in String array

Comment: @AnujVictor you can add string to a list such as List<String> myListString ; then convert to Arrays list; or you can define a String array with size as your list size and use a counter to add string to your string array. for example, define variable         String[] myArrayString = new String[list.Size()]   and fill it in outer for loop: myArrayString[i] = testString;

Comment: @AnujVictor I wrote a new answer (because it's to long for a comment ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Just as an answer to your comment: I just tried it and there is no exception at all:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("AREA_DS_ID", "1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33");
map.put("PROJECTS_ID", "13,78,267,18,28,33,55,99");
map.put("SIGNAL_NAME", "a");
map.put("ASSESSMENTNAME", "a");

List<String> entryList = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String value = entry.getKey() + '=' + entry.getValue();
    entryList.add(value);
    sb.append(value);
}
String[] entries = entryList.toArray(new String[entryList.size()]);
String mapAsString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: thanx buddy.. its cleared to me now. thanx a lot :)